# primefaces in-cell-editing control not update data in database

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
@Named(value = "viewtable")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class viewtable implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<viewbean> dlist = new ArrayList<viewbean>();
    ArrayList<Master> mlist = new ArrayList<Master>();


    public ArrayList<viewbean> getDlist() {
        return dlist;
    }

    public viewtable()  {
        get();
    }

    public void get() {
        try
        {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/mydsn");
            Connection con = ds.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from master");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                dlist.add(new viewbean(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getDate(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getBytes(7), rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11),rs.getDate(12),rs.getDate(13),rs.getString(14),rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16)));
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Conncetion pool db error-> "+ex);
        }
    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    }
}
```

The above code didn't update the data in the database in the `get()` method I've done any error and how to connect with the database using PrimeFaces.
I used a managed bean for save details from the database as a list called `mlist`.

JSF:

```
<h:form id="dtform">
    <p:growl showDetail="true" id="mess"/>
    <p:dataTable id="dt1" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="700" var="mas"  value="#{viewtable.dlist}" editable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Edit Here
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Regno" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText  value="#{mas.regno}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.regno}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Rollno" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.rollno}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.rollno}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Firstname" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.fname}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.fname}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Lastname" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.lname}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.lname}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="D.O.B" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.dob}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.dob}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Address" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.address}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.address}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Avatar" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.avatar}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.avatar}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Email" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.email}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.email}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Phno" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.phno}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.phno}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Dept" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.dept}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.dept}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.year}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.year}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Start" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.inidate}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.inidate}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="End" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.enddate}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.enddate}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Remarks" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.remarks}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.remarks}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Delivery" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.delivery}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.delivery}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Message" width="100">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mas.messdelivery}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mas.messdelivery}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Options" width="100">
            <p:rowEditor/>
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{viewtable.onEdit}" update=":dtform:mess"/>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: could you change the name of the method? it seems "get" is a kind of reserved words in java.

Comment: i tried but still problem....... please post me a sample code that how to integrate hibernate with primefaces datatable

Comment: does your method work? as far as i understand your code completely different from in cell editing. first of all you do a database select. can you post your prime facestags?

Comment: brother i posted my design part but i m facing this problem entire past 1 week please give some ideas

Comment: your in edit method is onEdit() in the managed bean. however you try to update data with get() method. do you want to use hibernate for this operation ? have a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf

Comment: friend i didnt try to update data using get method.... i just get the list of data from db.i revised ur link also there thy r using one function to create random list like that i tried but please post me some code how to edit database using onEdit method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have configured hibernate in your environment, and mapped your database to an entity class. you can update the records accordingly.

You can access the rows and update the records like :

```
    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
            YourHibernateEntity yourEntity = (YourHibernateEntity ) event.getObject());  
            SessionFactory sessFact = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();    
        Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
        Transaction  tran = sess.beginTransaction();
        sess.update(yourEntity );
        tran.commit();      

        }
```